# Generate text from MSI made using Wix

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wix

This might sound a dummy question, but I want to process the parameters given to the msi file, generated using Wix. I have developed the program for Visual C++ in VS2010 eg

```
msiexec /i setup.exe IP="192.168.2.1" PORT="9999"
```

I want to access those parameters IP and PORT and write those in a text file as:

```
{
"IP":"192.168.2.1",
"PORT":"9999"
}
```

Is this possible in Wix? If it isn't is there any way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a way to do this, although I haven't done it myself.

If you pass a parameter to the msiexec like the following:

```
msiexec /i setup.exe CUSTOMPROPIP="192.168.1.1" CUSTOMPROPPORT="9999"
```

Then that property should be set in the list of properties that the msi package can then parse.  You could then create a custom action that will handle these values and it can write a file to disk.

```
<Binary Id="SetupCA" SourceFile="SetupCA.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
```

Make sure you have this custom action in the Install sequences...

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Sequence="2" />
  ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You will need a custom action project that will create this SetupCA.CA.dll.  The code for the custom action will be something like:

```
namespace SetupCA
{
    public class CustomActions
    {

        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult WriteFileToDisk(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin WriteFileToDisk"); // This is useful to see when it is firing through the log file created during install with /l*vx parameter in msiexec

            // Do work here...
            string ipaddress = session["CUSTOMPROPIP"];
            string ipport = session["CUSTOMPROPPORT"];

            session.Log("Ending WriteFileToDisk");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be trying this code and let you know if this works. They btw